# How do I figure out how many snacks to put in a vending machine each day, given a function that predicts how many will be sold in one instant?

Tags: calculus

Not a homework question, just kind of studying calculus on my own.

Suppose I have to fill a vending machine with M&M packages tomorrow. To do that, I need to know how many M&M packages will be sold tomorrow (if there are enough in the machine, of course). I have a continuous function wherein I can plug in a specific time of day (e.g 12:00:01 PM) and the function will tell me how many will be sold at that time. Given this function, how can I figure out how many packages of M&M's I need to buy to meet tomorrow's demand?

Edit: Sounds to me like I could try finding the area under a curve. Maybe find the Rhiemann sum.

Comment: You'd need to integrate the function over a given interval (say, one day). Have you gotten that far in your studies yet?

Comment: @dmk I don't exactly follow a curriculum. I do think I understand what "integration" means - we use it to find the area under the function's curve, right?

Comment: That's correct, at least in the case of a definite integral (meaning we evaluate our antiderivative at the endpoints of the interval and find the difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since buying M&M's is a discrete operation (you buy $1$ at a specific time instant) it does not really make sense to have a continuously defined function to model its behavior.

Consider a similar question: We all know that M&M's come from a magic mountain which is connected to a conveyor belt. The Chocolate Man gets to speed up and slow down the conveyor belt as he wants. Now suppose we have a function $f$ which takes in a time and tells us how fast The Chocolate Man will decide to make the conveyor belt, i.e. the rate of M&M's per second. Now, how many boxes we should buy at the start of the day to make sure we have enough room to store all of the M&M's?

In this case, we would *integrate* the function $f$; that is, take the area under its curve. That will tell us how many M&M's The Chocolate Man will be sending down from the magic mountain that day and we will then know how many boxes we need to store all of the M&M's.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon to use continuous functions to approximate discrete-valued functions; often it simplifies matters a great deal.

Comment: @dmk I don't see how it makes sense at all for buying M&M's from a vending machine. This is the kind of purchase that happens, ,what, twenty times per day at an especially hungry office? Thus I changed the example.

Comment: I mean, sure, but would it cease to be inappropriate if OP were selling, I don't know, newspapers? The premise was that the function existed; presumably it does what it's supposed to do. (I'm guessing OP was speaking hypothetically, of course.) If the function tells us what we want it to, why not? Since OP wrote that he/she was learning, I simply wanted to point out that using a continuous function to model a discrete operation isn't on its face an invalid method.

Comment: @dmk Sure. I just find that the function as it is is very flawed. Suppose we put in some $t$ - an exact real number - into the function. What would the number it gives us even mean? It's not good to learn from faulty examples since it's hard to see the application in it.

Comment: To be clear, do you intend for your example to be a better example of a discrete operation approximated by a continuous function? Cos I didn't notice that the first time I read your response. (And the first sentence sorta primed me to not read it that way.)

Comment: @dmk Yes, you will find that mine is also a discrete operation, but a better example.

Comment: @Soke I don't want to be rude, but if I put the vending machine on a college campus, things might be different. Whatever discrete function I have could very well be very close to a continuous function. Regardless, I think we can agree that discrete scenarios can be perfect examples of integration in action.

Comment: @moonman239 I agree, discrete scenarios can - such as the one I proposed in my answer. Perhaps instead of "discrete" I should have used the word "sparse" - while the conveyor belt is a continuous wave of discrete M&M's, purchases of singular M&M's from a vending machine are a quite sparse operation which happen at a non-uniform rate. Though if you *really* wish to use the example you give, one thing you would have to change in order to integrate is that the function $f$ must give you the *rate* of M&M's sold per second rather than just number of M&M's sold.

Comment: @Soke: I must say, I think it's better to think of integrals in terms of totals (total M&M's sold/produced, etc, total vertical distance travelled by a ball in freefall, etc.) than as the area under a curve. As far as anyone's concerned, "area under a curve" could mean the area of a shape you make whose boundaries include the function.

Comment: @Soke Going along with your example, we can think of your f(t) as the derivative of g, a function which we can use to obtain the total number of M&Ms the Chocolate Man will have sent at every instant up to, and including, the instant represented by time t.